# Migrating existing Docker containers to Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have several running containers that were started by classic Docker commands. These containers are using a Docker network that was also created "by hand":

```
docker network create simple-network

docker run -d \
  --name docker-registry \
  --net=simple-network \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  -v [...] \
  registry:2.3.0

docker run -d \
  --name docker-registry-web \
  --net=simple-network \
  -p 8080 \
  -v [...] \
  hyper/docker-registry-web

docker run -d \
  --name nginx \
  --net=simple-network \
  -p 80:80 \
  -p 443:443 \
  -v [...] \
  nginx:1.9.8
```

I would like to use Docker Compose to run these containers as it would be easier to manage.

Is it possible to migrate these containers to Docker Compose like the following one or it's only possible to use compose with fresh new containers?

I would like to use the same volumes during this migration! Downtime is not a problem.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

docker-registry:
  image: registry:2.3.0
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes: 
    - [...]

docker-registry-web:
  image: hyper/docker-registry-web
  expose:
    - "8080"
  volumes: 
    - [...]

nginx:
  image: nginx:1.9.8
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes: 
    - [...]
```

Comment: Interesting question. Note that downtime will be minimal if you execute `docker kill container1 container2 ...; docker-compose up -d`. The containers however will not be exactly the same with that approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To re-use the existing network you can use

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: simple-network
```

To re-use the volumes, it depends on what kind of volumes they are. If they are named volumes you can do something similar:

```
volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: the_name_of_the_volume
```

You would then use `volumes: [data]` in a service to use it.

If they are host volumes then it is really easy, just use the same config.

If they are unnamed volumes you can use the volume id as an external volume (the same way you would use a named volume).

Re-using the containers isn't going to be possible. You can have Compose take over containers created by docker, but they need to have the correct `labels` on them. The easiest way to find the labels is to `docker inspect` a container created by compose to see the key/values.  Since you have to re-create a container anyway to apply labels, it's probably easier to just stop them and `up` compose.

Answer (score 2):

**Update to part of [dnephin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444646/dnephin) example of reusing named volumes, in case it helps the next person:**

It looks like in the volumes section of docker-compose.yml you aren't supposed to use `name: name_of_the_volume` anymore, just define them using the name e.g.

```
volumes:
  app-mongo-data:
    external: true
  app-mongo-config:
    external: true
```

then reference them in your services by (in this example) `app-mongo-data` or `app-mongo-config` like this:

```
version:'3'
services:
    app-db:
        image: mongo:latest
        expose:
          - "27017"
        volumes:
          - app-mongo-data:/data/db
          - app-mongo-config:/data/configdb
```

Might help with the networking side of the question (though not what was asked): the docker-compose.yml the above lines are from lets me reference my app's database using

`app-db:27017`

since compose includes a name resolver to listed services and the port was exposed to all services started by this compose.

[See 'external' section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the purpose of compose is to run multi container app. Whereas you might get something similar looking setup, but it seems unlikely that you can actually pull the running docker containers inside the docker compose environment.